# How to list outlook folders with Perl?

Tags: perl, outlook

I need help listing all folders in my Outlook inbox with Perl. I tried it using this code but cannot output prints nothing. I am such a beginner with Perl and I couldn't find any simple solution for this.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Win32::OLE qw(in with);
use Win32::OLE::Const 'Microsoft Outlook';
use Win32::OLE::Variant;

my $OL = Win32::OLE->GetActiveObject('Outlook.Application');

my $namespace = $OL->GetNamespace('MAPI');

my $all_folders = $namespace->all_folders();

print $all_folders;
```

Comment: [you can refer this](http://search.cpan.org/~duncan/Mail-Outlook-0.23/lib/Mail/Outlook.pm#NAME)

Comment: I tried but no luck :( you can see I have all_folders method inside of the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I finally come to the solution of my problem. Because I am using outlook at work, it has some predefined settings. We tested it with colleague from other country and we are working in the same company, but he has different settings in his outlook. So in my case I have three folders.

email.address@domain.com
archive
email.address@domain.com

I am not sure why my address is listed there twice but any way, all I had to do is to connect to my email address and then list all folders. Example here is to list every subfolder inside of the INBOX folder.

```
use strict;

#use warnings;


### This Perl Modules should be installed!

use Win32::OLE;
use Win32::OLE::Const 'Microsoft Excel'; # instead of the constants
use Win32::OLE::Const 'Microsoft Outlook';
use Win32::OLE qw(in with);
use Win32::OLE::Variant;


use IO::File;
use IO::Handle;
use Date::Calc qw(:all);

#jumps to outlook
my $OL = Win32::OLE->GetActiveObject('Outlook.Application');

#this is predefined namespace   
my $namespace = $OL->GetNamespace('MAPI');

#loop through all folders inside of the INBOX folder   
foreach my $i (1..$namespace->Folders->Count) {

       my $folder = $namespace->Folders("email.address\@domain.com")->Folders("Inbox")->Folders($i)->Name;

       print $folder, "....\n";                    
    }
```

Problem solved :).

Also a note -> you might have different settings in your outlook so in that case you could delete first folder - Folders("email.address\@domain.com") - or at least this is how it works with my colleagues outlook.